# When using Intent.putExtra() and Intent.getStringExtra(), are we working with the Bundle?

Tags: android, android-intent, bundle

Simple and silly question, but I couldn't confirm it yet.

From what I understood and tested, `Intent.getStringExtra()` is the same as `Intent.getExtras().getString()` (assuming we have data to fetch).

From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getStringExtra(java.lang.String)), what `Intent.getStringExtra()` does:

> Retrieve extended data from the intent.

Is `Intent.getStringExtra()` extracting this *extended data* from its `Bundle`?

Please provide a reference to your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you're getting the data from the `Bundle`.  That's why the `Bundle` is called `Extras` and all the functions are called `getXXXExtras`.  They're convenience methods to avoid repeatedly calling `getExtras().getXXX`.  For a reference-  do your own research, the Android source code is open source.  A quick google search will find a dozen copies.

Comment: I asked this question cause I Googled and didn't find a reference specifically saying "getStringExtra() gets data from the Intent's Bundle..." I confirmed it in the Android's code now, but you could have just referenced it instead of telling me to "do your own research"

Comment: Btw found the code at: https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/content/Intent.java